# How to check if a text paragraph contains words available in string array?

Tags: java, arrays

I have a text paragraph stored in String variable and String array containing multiple values like

```
String names[] = {"jack", "adam", "jerry adams", "Jon snow"};
```

How do i check if text paragraph ( which is stored in String variable) contains the value given in name array?

Comment: can you provide an example please?

Comment: Do you need contain at least one value from an array or all values?

Comment: @EduardGrinchenko all values.

Answer (score 2):

Lonely Neuron method checks and returns true if any one of the string in array is present in the paragraph.

To check if all values in array(as mentioned in comment) are present in paragraph, this slight modification would be needed.

```
public static boolean textContainsAny(String text, String[] names) {
    for (String name : names) {
        if (!text.contains(name)) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This may be slightly advanced, but:

```
String names[] = {"jack", "adam", "jerry adams", "Jon snow"};
String paragraph = "jack and jill went up the hill to meet jerry adams";
boolean onefound = Stream.of(names).anyMatch(paragraph::contains);
bollean allfound = Stream.of(names).allMatch(paragraph::contains);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following one-liner

`boolean contained = Arrays.stream(names)
   .noneMatch(name -> !paragraph.contains(name));`

Note that it is going to be a case sensitive match. `Jack` is not the same as `jack`.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
public boolean textContainsAny(String text, String[] names) {
    for (String name : names) {
        if (text.contains(name)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

With `for (String name : names)` we iterate over all values in `names` so we can check each `name` separately. We then call `text.contains(name)` to check if that particular name is contained. If any name is contained, it immediately returns `true` and the rest of the loop doesn't have to get executed. If we have tested all `name`s, it will return `false`, indicating no names was contained in the `text`. We do this in a separate method so the code is reusable.

You can then call it like that:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String text = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore";
    String names = new String[]{"jack", "adam", "jerry adams", "Jon snow"};
    System.out.println("name is contained: " + textContainsAny(text, names));
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Lonely Let me check and let you know here.

Comment: sure, go ahead and tell me if you need anything else

Comment: Note that this is an O(n^2) solution, you can improve it to an O(n) solution using a Map for example.

Comment: @rodrigoap that is true, but it seems like the question asker is on a level of programming where `Map`s are out of scope. Programming needs to be learned gradually and you can't force higher level solution on newcomers. It will only alienate them

Comment: @LonelyNeuron I agree. Also, giving working code to someone that is learning won't help him either.

Comment: @rodrigoap you are (mostly) right and I actually meant to provide more context in an edit, but got distracted. I now added the explanation of what is happening ;)

Comment: How would use use a Map in this case? @rodrigoap

Comment: @DodgyCodeException well, if you had to check for **a lot** of strings, you could put every word in `text` into a `Map`. but it would still not be semantically equivalent and it is a **very** specific usecase - surely not what @linuxgenie needs

Comment: @rodrigoap that would be the way, if the OP wanted to check words. But he wants to check names, sometimes single words and sometimes two (first+surname) or maybe three. So you can't split the paragraph into words.